Объясните, пожалуйста, наличие запятой в предложении-примере из ПАС? И кто ОНА?
Присутствие здесь декабристов, разбросанных в ссылке по всем просторам Западной и Восточной Сибири, имело на общественность такое влияние, что, во-первых, будучи во многих местах разрозненными умами, ОНА стала общественностью, и, во-вторых, обрела цели, которые в конце концов привели к открытию Томского университета (Расп.)
Поле слова "общественностью" - союз И соединяет однородные члены, не должно быть запятой. Или всё не так?
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126 п.91

Ошибка в правилах ПАС:
Но добро есть добро, в каких бы обстоятельствах оно ни творилось, и для нашего темного в ту пору и малоизученного края их деятельность в науке, культуре и просто нравственном и личностном воспитании явилась огромным благом. Одно присутствие здесь декабристов, разбросанных в ссылке по всем просторам Западной и Восточной Сибири, имело на общественность такое влияние, что, во-первых, будучи во многих местах разрозненными умами, она стала общественностью И, во-вторых, обрела цели, которые в конце концов привели к открытию Томского университета.
https://www.rulit.me/books/sibir-sibir-read-402199-6.html
